# Error while mirroring a git repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am running into below error while mirroring a git repose don't see these tags as existing ,is there a different command I can use to mirror the the git repo?

```
-bash-4.1$ git push --mirror git@gitlab.sd.company.com:techFirmware/PROJECTmirror.git
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.55 KiB, done.
Total 9 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to change existing tags on this project.
To git@gitlab.sd.apple.com:techFirmware/PROJECTmirror.git
 ! [remote rejected] PROJECT1310T472R15_BRANCH_13_45 -> PROJECT1310T472R15_BRANCH_13_45 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] PROJECT1310T472R15_REL_13_45_63 -> PROJECT1310T472R15_REL_13_45_63 (pre-receive hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] PROJECT1310T472R15_REL_13_45_63_RETAG -> PROJECT1310T472R15_REL_13_45_63_RETAG (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.sd.company.com:techFirmware/PROJECTmirror.git'
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have permissions from gitlab to be able to do that. I'm not sure a separate command would help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of your GitLab server.
See [issue 25175](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25175), which duplicates [issue 24813](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24813) and was fixed with [MR 7700](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/7700) (GitLab 8.14.2): Tags can't be created with Developer permissions anymore.

> It might just be that GitLab thinks it's an existing tag, even when it's a new tag.

Check if you are the owner of the repository you are pushing to, which should be a new empty repository (in order to import, through the `push --mirror`, the content of your local repo).